# Picking up kippah that blew off on shabbat in karmalit

Tags: halacha, shabbat, kippa-yarmulka, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

A kippa has blown off someone's head on shabbat in an area without an eruv. The kippa is now on the ground. How should one respond? Would the same apply to dropped gloves or key belts etc. 
Pick it up and wear it? 
Leave it? 
Find someone who is not Jewish and ask for assistance?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to put it on?

Comment: My assumption has always been that picking up to wear something would not be part of the prohibitions of akira/hanacha. However, I am questioning if my assumptions that picking up something to wear is not akira/hanacha.

Comment: To qualify as *hotzaah* would require transferring from one reshus to another.  I suspect a person standing in a *reshus* doesn't himself qualify as a separate *reshus* to effect *hotzaah*, even though putting something on would qualify as a *hanacha*.

Comment: Putting it on after walking 4 amos though would seem to constitute the Rabbinic prohibition in a karmalis and the biblical one in a reshus harabim.

Comment: Not an answer - but interesting source - see משנה ברורה, שא, כ that says "אסור לצאת בו - דלמא נפיל ואתי לאתויינהו ד' אמות ברשות הרבים"

Comment: Interesting Zvika, The mishna brurah source is more about what one can wear when walking in a reshut harabim. One of the concerns mentioned there is the item that is loose or taken off regularly would lead one to carry it. If a kippa is considered to be in this category, which it is not, than it would be prohibited to wear it altogether when going from reshut to reshut!

Comment: This question and it’s answers sound really interesting to me but it’s just a shame the context is missing a bit for non-Jews.

Answer (score 4):

If a person who drops an item of clothing that he was wearing in the road  (kippa, belt jacket etc.) on Shabbos he should:.
**1.** pick it up (akira)  without moving outside  4 amos cubits(cubit is about 49cm) from its resting pace (the floor) to its new place (to clothe his body)*
**2.** wear it and wait without walking further (hanacha).
**3.** After standing still for a few seconds deliberately **without doing anything**(e.g adjusting the clothing)**  he can start a new Akira wearing the clothing(having completed the Akira  and hanacha beheter of putting on his clothing within 4 amos) and go where ever he wants to go (as now that he is wearing that clothing he is no longer carrying it as its part of his body.)***

If however he found an item in the road that he can't wear he must leave it and cannot  tell a gentile to take for him unless he asks a Rabbi for a specific situation in a Carmelis (less than 600,000 people in that road), like bringing a Mila knife to perform a Bris CYLOR.

Gauntlets/gloves are subject to debate whether since they are clothing to wear it is permitted in public Domain, or prohibited in case one might take them off (with other clothing e.g couple belt one does not take them off so its fine to wear)****

---

Sources:
*It is permitted to transport something less than 4 amos  in the Reshus Harabim (public domain and same applies to Carmlis). Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 349,1:
כל אדם יש לו ארבע אמות ברשות הרבים שיכול לטלטל בהם

**Not pausing after standing still arranging the couple is one long movement and the next time you stop outside those 4 amos you are transgressing. and is forbidden Shabbos 5b:תוך ד' אמות - עמד לפוש פטור, לכתף חייב.

***See Shulchan aruch 301,7 wearing clothes is not carrying.

****Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 301,7: 
 מותר לצאת בשבת בבתי ידים הנקראים גואנטי"ש ויש מי שמחמיר להצריך שיתפרם מערב שבת בבתי ידים של מלבושיו או שיקשרם בהם בקשר של קיימא יפה וראוי לחוש לדבריו
Magen Avraham: שיתפרם:    שמא ישכח ויעבירנו ד"א

Comment: Why do you have to wait a minute? Doesn't Zero velocity = Hanacha. Why isn't stopping for a second satisfactory?

Comment: @MDjava when i say a minute i mean to consciously stop and not move if you only wait the time that it take to put on the kippah then he is carrying without stopping because this is called "stopping to load oneself" which is not considerred stopping

Comment: Ok, I don't know more than the relevant Gemara about Omed LeKatef, which I think you're referring to, but that sounds like a good point.

Answer (score 0):

See Igrot Moshe (OC sect2 siman 112) where there is a discussion if putting on a hat on one's head in a *reshut harabim* that one was already carrying is considered hanacha or not. He concludes with the following that if one discovered a kippa or hat in a pocket that one had forgotten about while walking, one should not put it on immediately. Rather, drop it via k'lachar yad and then put it on so as not to incur a loss. This is similar to Ribiat page 1333-1334 (see footnotes 201-202). It would seem to me that in the question at hand, if the wind blew the kippa, one could pick it up and replace it on the spot.

שו"ת אגרות משה אורח חיים חלק ב סימן קיב

ונמצא לפ"ז שבשכח והוציא בגד כרוך דרך משא מהבית או יארמולקע /כיפה/ בכיס בגדו אסור לו כשנזכר ברה"ר ללבשם דרך הלוכו דהרי יעשה בזה הנחה אלא טוב לו יותר לרוץ כמו בחבילתו מונחת לו על כתפו שבשבת דף קנ"ג ולזרוק כלאחר יד כי מטא לביתו. אבל באלו נראה שתיכף כשנזכר יזרוק להו כלאחר יד **ואח"כ יקחנו וילבשנו במקום שנפל** דכיון דיכול לזרוק תיכף ולא יהיה לו הפסד מסתבר שאסור לו לישא כל הדרך אף בריצה.

Comment: That's not the same at all.  If you pick it up from the ground and put it right on, you've done an akira and a hanacha, but you haven't moved it 4 amos.  This is 100% permitted.